# System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize adds \u0022

Tags: c#

How can I set JsonSerializer to not add "\u0022" to string for EventData property? Because I get:

> {"Id":5,"CreateDate":"2021-04-21T05:26:30.9817284Z","EventData":"{\u0022Id\u0022:1,\u0022Email\u0022:\u0022test@test.test\u0022}"}

I will never deserialize EventData, it must be readable. And I want:

> ```
> {"Id":5,"CreateDate":"2021-04-21T05:26:30.9817284Z","EventData":"{Id:1,Email:test@test.test}"}
> ```

My code:

```
public class EmailSent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class UserCreated
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string EventData { get; set; }
}

var emailSent = new EmailSent
{
    Id = 1,
    Email = "test@test.test"
};

var userCreated = new UserCreated
{
    Id = 5,
    CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    EventData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(emailSent) // I will never deserialize it
};

string result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userCreated);
```

Comment: have you tried `String.Replace`? or alternatively: _not_ creating nested JSON?

Comment: By `\u0022` you mean double quotes. This is because you stored a string with double quotes in it, in a string property that will be serialized. It's either `\u0022` or adding `\"` everywhere when serializing. If you don't want the double quotes in the string, you will have to remove them manually.

Answer (score 29):

You can use, for example, `UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping`:

```
var serializeOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(userCreated, serializeOptions);
```

This will produce the following output:

```
{
  "Id": 5,
  "CreateDate": "2021-04-21T07:49:23.4378969Z",
  "EventData": "{\"Id\":1,\"Email\":\"test@test.test\"}"
}
```

Reference: [How to customize character encoding with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding). Please read the caution there:

> **Caution**
>
> Compared to the default encoder, the UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping encoder is more permissive about allowing characters to pass through unescaped:
> (...)

Answer (score 8):

This happens because JsonSerializer.Serialize() is invoked more than once.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can specify 'JSONSerializerOptions' Encoder equal to JavaScriptEncoder. Create(new TextEncoderSettings(UnicodeRanges.All))
like this

```
public static string ToString(this object str)
{
    try
    {
         string sResult = JsonSerializer.Serialize(str, new JsonSerializerOptions{WriteIndented = true, Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.Create(new TextEncoderSettings(System.Text.Unicode.UnicodeRanges.All))});
         return sResult;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the exact same problem, only my UserCreated is being returned by ASP.NET controller function, I don't directly control serialization.

The simplest solution is to change the type of EventData to JsonNode.

To set EventData from whatever complex object you want, you can use this awkward construct

```
EventData = JsonNode.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(complexData))
```

Complete minimal example:

```
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> complexData =
            new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A", "B" } };

        NestedJason toSerialize = new NestedJason()
        {
            FormName = "String",
            FormData = JsonNode.Parse(JsonSerializer.Serialize(complexData))
        };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(toSerialize)); 
        // prints {"FormName":"String","FormData":{"A":"B"}}
    }
}

public class NestedJason
{
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public JsonNode FormData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner option is to make `FormData` type `object`.  (I'm assuming you don't want to make it type `EmailSent` because you want to store random data about many different types of events.)

If you round trip the `EventData` as `object`, it will go in as `EmailSent` and come back out as `JsonElement`.  Manual steps would be required to get it back to an `EmailSent`.

```
public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> complexData =
            new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "A", "B" } };

        NestedJason toSerialize = new NestedJason()
        {
            FormName = "Sting",
            FormData = complexData
        };

        Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(toSerialize));

        NestedJason result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(
                                JsonSerializer.Serialize(toSerialize),
                                typeof(NestedJason)) as NestedJason;

        Console.WriteLine(result.FormData.GetType().Name);
    }
}

public class NestedJason
{
    public string FormName { get; set; }
    public Object FormData { get; set; }
}
```

(I personally will be using the previous JsonNode option, that is more editable, but the object option skips that round trip serialization kludge.)