# Adding root node to json structure

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have below json structure. I need to add extra tag element documents as a list to entire my json structure. Please advise how can I achieve this.

```json
{
  "issuer": {
    "address": {
      "branchID": " ",
      "country": " ",
      "governate": " "
    }
  }
}
```

Expecting below Output:

```json
{
  "documents": [
    {
      "issuer": {
        "address": {
          "branchID": " ",
          "country": " ",
          "governate": " "
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more information, how do you try to achive this problem using C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most proper way to do it tbh (hacky solution) but if you have access to the input you can modify your input before serializing to json.

```
var inputJson = "{\"issuer\":{\"address\":{\"branchID\":\"\",\"country\":\"\",\"governate\":\"\"}}}";
var stringifiedJson = "{\"documents\": [" + inputJson + "]}";   
Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize<dynamic>(stringifiedJson, new JsonSerializerOptions() {WriteIndented = true}));
```

dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdM7ln

Assumptions:

1. You recieve this json as an input. If you are the one creating it then make a list documents and serialize that instead.
2. I assumed you are using `System.Text.Json` but the above should work with any serializer.

ps: Check [System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize adds \u0022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67189964/system-text-json-jsonserializer-serialize-adds-u0022) for the u0022 if needed

Comment: Its working. but please I need final response without \ backslashes.

Comment: I created a new dotnet fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8lIjZ
You will see 2 methods there. 
If you serialize and serialize the object `DeserializeAndSerialize` you don't have to bother with escape characters since dotnet will hanble the escape characters internally. 
If you want to serialize only then you will have to escape them yourself (use `SerializeAndReplace`)